# Multi tab Excel sheets, unique entries in 1 column, create new file with data from another column as the name, all with headers

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx, xlsxwriter

As usual, I've bitten off more than I can chew.
I have a file, "list.xlsx". The file has 3 sheets, "current students", "finished" and "cancelled".
The sheets all contain data under the following headers
[StudentId, FirstName, Lastname, DoB, Nationality, CourseID, CourseName, Startdate, Finishdate, UnitID, UnitName, UnitCompetency]

I've created the below abomination that starts off what I need.

What I want it to do is:

1) Create a file with FirstName + Lastname.xlsx based off of the StudentId (unique) in the folder named after their sheet

2) In that file, take all information from the rest of the columns and append it to their file

```
    #python 3.8
import pandas as pd
import os
import shutil

file = "list.xlsx"
CS = "current student"
Fin = "finished"
Can = "cancelled"
TheList = {CS, Fin, Can}
CanXlsx = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = Can)
FinXlsx = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = Fin)
CSXlsx = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = CS)

if os.path.exists(CS):
    shutil.rmtree(CS)
os.mkdir(CS)
CSDir = '//current student//'
if os.path.exists(Fin):
    shutil.rmtree(Fin)
os.mkdir(Fin)
FinDir = '//finished//'
if os.path.exists(Can):
    shutil.rmtree(Can)
os.mkdir(Can)
CanDir = '//cancelled//'

CancelID = CanXlsx.StudentId.unique()
FinID = FinXlsx.StudentId.unique()
CSID = CSXlsx.StudentId.unique()
```

I thought I was getting better with for loops and the like, but can't seem to get my head around them.
I can think about the logic, but it just doesn't come through with the code.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/134fqWx6veF7zp_12GqFYlbmPZnK8ihaV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Just to this straight you want to get a file per each student on each spreadsheet. In that case, each file will contain only one row of information? Because it will be filled with the student data, is that correct?

Comment: do u mind sharing a sample of one of the sheets? data, not pics. also you can read in all the sheets at a go, if they all have the same columns, simply pass sheet_name=None when reading in the data

Comment: I've added a .xlsx link to GDrive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the approach needed for this is to create 3 data frames (probably is possible to do it with one, but I don't remember). 1) Then, on each data frame, you will need to extract a list of "First Name + Last Name", and after that, 2) you will need to create masks on the data frames to extract the information and save it.

```py
import os
import shutil

file = "list.xlsx"
CS = "current student"
Fin = "finished"
Can = "cancelled"
TheList = {CS, Fin, Can}
CanXlsx = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = Can)
FinXlsx = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = Fin)
CSXlsx = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = CS)

## File Creation
if os.path.exists(CS):
    shutil.rmtree(CS)
os.mkdir(CS)
CSDir = '//current student//'
if os.path.exists(Fin):
    shutil.rmtree(Fin)
os.mkdir(Fin)
FinDir = '//finished//'
if os.path.exists(Can):
    shutil.rmtree(Can)
os.mkdir(Can)
CanDir = '//cancelled//'

# Create full names
CanXlsx["Fullname"] = CanXlsx["StudentId"] + "_" + CanXlsx["First Name"] + "_" + CanXlsx["Last Name"]
## Same for the other dfs

# Get a list of ids
# canFullNames = list(CanXlsx["Fullname"]) Edit: Preferred approach through student Ids
canIds = list(CanXlsx["StudentId"])
## Same for the other dfs

# Loop over the list of full names to create your df
for id in canIds:
    df1 = CanXlsx[CanXlsx["StudenId"] == id] # This will filter the rows by the id you want
    # Retrieve the full name
    name = df1.iloc[0]["Fullname"]

    # Create the filename
    filename = os.path.join(CanDir,name + ".xlsx")

    df1.drop(columns = ["First Name", "Last Name"] # I understand that these columns are not required on each file
    df1.to_excel(filename,header=True,index=False)

## Same for the other dfs
```

Let me know if this helps, at least this is what I understood you want to achieve with your code. :D

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I've only just got a chance to play with it a little bit. I keep getting an error with the "df" in the name loop. Should this link back to canFullNames? Also, names are not unique, is there a way to check the Student ID column "CancelID = CanXlsx.StudentId.unique()" and only use names linked to unique Student IDs?

Comment: Glad that it helped. Let me know if you have any questions and good luck with your project!

Comment: You're online! Sorry, pushed enter trying to get a new line :)

Comment: Yes, if you don't have unique names, is possible to check Id's instead, let me edit my answer then.

Comment: Please check the edition of this post hopefully, that will help!

Comment: NameError: name 'df' is not defined

Comment: df1.to_excel(os.path.join(can,f"{name}.xlsx"),header=True,index=False)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211035/discussion-between-enriquebet-and-adrian-charles-blood).